# How to know if cell is first in section

Tags: iphone, uitableview

When customizing an UITableView, how can I know wether the cell is the first, last or only one in the section in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
```

method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out if it is the last row in a section, call `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` on the data source delegate (presumably, it's `self`, since you are in a `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method). If the value returned from that method equals `indexPath.row+1`, you are at the last row. If additionally `indexPath.row == 0`, you are at the only row. If `indexPath.row == 0` but `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returned a number other than 1, you are looking at the first row in a section.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger count = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
    BOOL first = indexPath.row == 0;
    BOOL last = indexPath.row+1 == count;
    if (first && last) {
        NSLog(@"The only cell in section %d", indexPath.section);
    } else if (first) {
        NSLog(@"The first cell in section %d", indexPath.section);
    } else if (last) {
        NSLog(@"The last cell in section %d", indexPath.section);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Nothing special...");
    }
    // Do the rest of your work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSIndexPath` has all the information you need. Row and section.